# Finding unneeded library references in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio

I seem to have gotten a bit carried away with the number of libraries I'm referencing in a ASP.Net MVC web application I'm working on. Is there any tools or features already built into Visual Studio 2008/2010 which indicates to me which references I don't need?

Comment: Remove them one at a time and compile. If you can't compile, it is needed.

Comment: @Oded. That's a bit tedious though especially having to add back in those you find you actually need.

Comment: Guess you just learned a valuable lesson... I find that I only really learn such lessons if it hurts ;)

Comment: Or do it the other way around: remove all references, see what doesn't compile, add all required references for things that don't compile, and repeat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/96279/visual-studio-detecting-unneeded-assemblies) older SO question and answer.

Resharper will do this for you, with its `clean code` context menu.