# Remove unused references

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I want to know if any tool exists for removing unused references (**not** unused `using` directives) within a .NET C# project.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/81597/remove-unused-references-using

Comment: Possible Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/81597/remove-unused-references-using

Comment: Notifying the duplicate post got duplicated.. funny huh... :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Tools for finding unused references](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/142627/tools-for-finding-unused-references)

Comment: Unfortunately, in `VB.NET` this comes out of the box (built in Visual Studio), but not in `C#` ... :-(

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing all unused references from a project in Visual Studio projects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3157066/removing-all-unused-references-from-a-project-in-visual-studio-projects)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I am unaware of such a tool off the top of my head - I do know that Visual Studio does not include one by default. However, referenced assemblies that are not actually used by code in the project are automatically removed by the C# compiler from the list of assemblies referenced by the compiled program. If you use [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/), you can compare the list of actual references to the list of references in the project, and remove the unnecessary ones that the project includes based on that.

Comment: how can I use it in VS 2008? I cannot find it.

Comment: .NET Reflector is a free (and essential) program from redgate: http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/

Comment: Reflector is Redgate Reflector which can be found here: http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/

Comment: Reflector is no longer free :(

Comment: Using ILSpy, an open-source .NET assembly browser and decompiler, you can get a list of actual references. Open the assembly in ILSpy and look for the 'References' node. Beware that a reference may contain a reference to another assembly!

Answer (score 9):

Resharper will certainly do the trick...

Answer (score 2):

JetBrains Resharper adds a menu item *Remove Unused References* to the *References* node's context menu in the *Solution Explorer*.

When you click it, it'll scan you project and list references which can be removed. You can further select which ones you want to remove.

Comment: It also includes an "Optimize references" option which parses your source code as well to remove nuget and other items. Very useful.

Answer (score 0):

Resharper has that option.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [Productivity Power-tool Plugin](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d0d33361-18e2-46c0-8ff2-4adea1e34fef)

Removing unused references from project is one of the many helpful features it has. It is free and it has some of the [R# features](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/).

Comment: Are you sure? It doesn't seem to have the option.

Comment: This answer is wrong. Productivity power tools can remove unused `using` statements, but not unused references.

Answer (score 0):

**ResolveUR** - Resolve Unused Referencese Unused References

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=battas.ResolveUR-ResolveUnusedReferences

*Works with Visual Studio 2013, 2015, 2017 and 2019*

Comment: Doesn't work with 2019 unless you manually edit installation config files

Comment: @Tzwenni Works with 2019 16.0 or older... I think you are using 16.5 or newer