# Is there a way to see a namespaces reference?

Tags: c#, umbraco

I am attempting to tidy up a project by removing anything redundant from it. My issue is that there are many references and I am wondering is there a way I can see which namespaces link to any references so I can remove any references that are not used? Does this make sense if not ill try and rephrase? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Dependency Walker shows all the dependent library.I think you can use this for.

Comment: Namespaces and references are *somewhat* orthogonal, in that many assemblies can contribute to the same namespace, and a single assembly can contribute to many namespaces. If you're looking for unused assembly references, perhaps NDepend can help?

Comment: Download the trial of this http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/download/, it will just do that for you and you will come to love it

Comment: Cool cheers guys ill let you know how it goes

Comment: This is a great response to what's more-or-less the same question:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/1382776/2150286

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out by @SQL.NET Warrior you can easily remove unused references using [Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/download/). You just have to Right click on project -> Refactor->Remove unused references

Or you can use Visual studio extension - [Remove Unused references](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/9811e528-cfa8-4fe7-9dd1-4021978b5097) written by [Spongman](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5961469/442444)

Comment: Resharper is awesome, but be weary of removing 'unused' references - test! R# seems to consider a used reference one that gets called from a codebehind. A dll like Telerik controls that may be used only on a markup page or otherwise not referenced by code, will not trigger a reference use and be removed - which is a fail. Your project may still build in VS but will actually throw in use. I encourage using the [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227976(v=vs.90).aspx)aspnet compiler to do a precompile test[/link] before committing. test!test!

Answer (score 1):

[Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/download/) can remove unused references and also can remove unused namespaces within files if you are brave enough to apply it from solution level.